# fnObj = window[functionName] is not a function issue - eval() works well

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm just overworking my JS code and wish to replace my `eval()`'s with `window[functionName]`. So I just made a quick test in the JSFiddle and all works well with the following lines:

```
var fnName = "Page_test";
var foo = "yammy";
var Page_test = function(bar) {
    return bar;
}
var Obj = window[fnName];
alert(Obj(foo));
```

(*Link to this JSFiddle* -> http://jsfiddle.net/juSHj/)

Now I try to replace the following lines of code with the evil `eval()` with the above concept:

**old code:** (works like a charm / fired after ajax success)

```
 ...
 success: function(ret) {
     if(returnFnAjaxForm != "") {
          eval(returnFnAjaxForm+"('"+encodeURI(jQuery.trim(ret))+"')");
     }
 }
 ...
```

**new code:**

> Returns: Uncaught TypeError: Property 'dummyFn' of object [object
>   Window] is not a function

```
...
success: function(ret) {
     if(returnFnAjaxForm != "") {
          fnObj = window[returnFnAjaxForm];
          if(typeof(fnObj) == "function") { // this is optional
               fnObj(encodeURI(jQuery.trim(ret)));
          }
     }
} 
...
```

I'm curious where I made my mistake. Yes the function I try to fire exists and is defined with `var` . Is this concept may not possible to use it on an ajax-response?

Thanks for any help.

(Using jQuery)

Comment: `dummyFn` does not occur in your code samples. Did you paste the right code? Also, this looks to be the right approach, the error is probably somewhere else / something silly.

Comment: `Page_test` and `dummyFn` are not members of the window most likely. Where is that code ran? within a scope such as `$(function(){...})`?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen the `dummyFn` is just for example for the dynamically loaded code. Theres only an error in the console when I fire them this way - works well without any error while I use eval()

Comment: @KevinB yes, both functions are inside the same `$(function() {...});`  but I cannot copy the whole JS due to its size.

Comment: @godesign If you are in a `$(function() {...})`, my answer should be the solution.

Comment: ideally you would not have these things sitting in window scope, it would be in some object.  `var myMethods = { foo : function(){} }; myMethods["foo"]();`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you declare your function in a closure, it's not a member of window. Example :

```
var in_window = '132';
alert(window['in_window']); // Alert 132

(function() {
    var not_in_window = '132';
    alert(window['not_in_window']); // Alert undefined
})();
```

So be careful of where you declare your `Page_test` variable. If you really want to put in window, you can do `window.Page_test = Page_test`.

The best you can do is to use an object for all your possible callbacks. Like this :

```
var callbacks = {
    foo : function() {},
    foo1 : function() {},
    foo2 : function() {},
    foo3 : function() {}
};

var obj = callbacks[fnName];
```

Comment: Right, since the `eval` code doesn't actually use `window[returnFnAjaxForm]` but just `returnFnAjaxForm`. This might be it :)

Comment: thanks, this comes my problem pretty close. Both function running inside `$(function() { ... });` - so would I be able to use something like `this['functionName']` ?

Comment: @godesign No you can't use `this` to retrieve variables. I just edited my answer.

Comment: @Magnus - great addition, I'll accept your answer in a minute. Thank you all.

Comment: @Magus, good answer with multiple choice callback option which I want